# I want to mint and transfer 1 erc20(custom) to the minter itself, just to track erc20 transaction

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20, erc721

This is the code used, I am using polygon testnet for testing, the approve function is working fine but transferFrom is not working(error: -32000)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

import "@0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token-metadata.sol";
import "@0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/ownership/ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract newNFT is NFTokenMetadata, Ownable {
    ERC20 KOOLToken;

    constructor() {
        KOOLToken=ERC20(0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
        nftName = "Test NFT 123";
        nftSymbol = "TNFT321";
    }

    function approve() public onlyOwner {
      KOOLToken.approve(address(msg.sender), 1);
    }

function transferFrom() public onlyOwner{
  KOOLToken.transferFrom(msg.sender,msg.sender, 1);
}

function mint(address _to, uint256 _tokenId, string calldata _uri) public onlyOwner {
  super._mint(_to, _tokenId);
  super._setTokenUri(_tokenId, _uri);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better your problem? What mean 'transfer 1 erc20(custom) to the minter itself'?

Comment: I mean I have my own erc20 token, so I want to send 1 token to the minter itself, eg if address A mints an nft then A has to pay 1 token to itself, just that an erc20 transaction showes up in the blockchain explorer

Comment: in simple terms, I want to send my erc20 token to the minter with the help of approve and transferfrom function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `-32000` error is caused by a revert in the ERC20 contract, because msg.sender does't have enough allowance to spend.

According to [EIP20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20), `transferFrom` provides:

> The transferFrom method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing contracts to transfer tokens on your behalf. This can be used for example to allow a contract to transfer tokens on your behalf and/or to charge fees in sub-currencies. The function SHOULD throw unless the _from account has deliberately authorized the sender of the message via some mechanism.

Which means,even though the `msg.sender` is the owner here, it is not a valid source address for `transferFrom` unless you call `approve` on it before.

You can approve the `msg.sender`, or simply use `transfer` function.